# Importrange following another importrange

Tags: arrays, import, syntax, range, google-sheets-formula

Is it possible to have one importrange follow another?

The purpose of this would be where there are such large data sets that they have needed to be put into different separate sheets to collate other data and now parts of the sheets need to be put back into one sheet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can have them in array like:

```
={IMPORTRANGE("url1"; "sheetname!A1:C10"); 
  IMPORTRANGE("url2"; "sheetname!A1:C10")}
```

but before you do so each unique importrange needs to be run as standalone function to connect the sheets by allowing access - if not you will get an array error